# Tkinter passing callback function result to another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I wonder how to pass return value from one class to another class in tkinter.
In my program I have `DataChosenForm` class where I want to choose option in `Combobox` and pass this result to another class `ReturnData` to set a variable in a `Label`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class DataChosenForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        chosen = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="wybór")
        chosen.grid(row=0)
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(chosen)
        self.combo['values'] = ('wizz', 'ryanair', 'lot')
        self.combo.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=80, pady=10)
        self.combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.callback)

    def callback(self, event=None):
        if event.widget.get() == 'wizz':
            print('wizz')
            return 'wizz'
        elif event.widget.get() == 'ryanair':
            print('ryanair')
            return 'ryanair'
        elif event.widget.get() == 'lot':
            print('lot')
            return 'lot'

class ReturnData(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        var = tk.StringVar()
        message_box = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="wynik")
        message_box.grid(row=1)
        mb = tk.Label(message_box, textvariable=var,anchor='nw')
        mb.pack(padx=120, pady=30)

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("program do wyszukiwania cen lotów")
        self.geometry('300x200')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        DataChosenForm(self).grid(row=0, column=0)
        ReturnData(self).grid(row=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Julia Please don't edit code, we can't know if the code was incompetently copy/pasted here or if the indentation errors are part of the problem they are asking about.

Comment: Sorry, indentations are not a problem. I wrong copied my code and I didn't catch this indentations mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Julia has the basically the right architecture for your tkinter application, but her answer could be improved by using a tkinter `Variable` — because all widgets associated with one will automatically update their displayed value whenever the `Variable` is changed (by one of them or something else).

Here's a little documentation on [Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). Note that since `ttk.Combobox` with have all the methods of a `tk.Entry` widgets, here's a bit of documentation about them (which also happens to illustrate the "pattern" of using of a `StringVar` in conjunction with one so it also applies to a `ttk.Combobox`s).

Generally, you can tell a widget to use a tkinter `Variable` by specifying an instance of one as the option `textvariable=` keyword argument when the widget is created. You can also set the option using the partial dictionary interface most widgets support, so assignments like `widget['textvariable'] = variable` are another way to make use of them — the code below makes use of both of these ways.

Here's Julia's code modified to use a `tk.StringVar`. Note the `Combobox` *doesn't* need a callback function to bind the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event to it, so all that complexity has been eliminated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class DataChosenForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        choice = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="wybór")
        choice.grid(row=0)
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(choice)
        self.combo['textvariable'] = parent.var  # Use shared variable.
        self.combo['values'] = ('wizzair', 'ryanair', 'lot')
        self.combo.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=80, pady=10)

class ReturnData(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        message_box = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="wynik")
        message_box.grid(row=1)
        mb = tk.Label(message_box, textvariable=parent.var,  # Use shared variable.
                      anchor='nw', width=20)
        mb.pack(padx=120, pady=30)

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("program do wyszukiwania cen lotów")
        self.geometry('300x200')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.var = tk.StringVar(value='Dokonać wyboru')  # Create shared variable.

        DataChosenForm(self).grid(row=0, column=0)
        ReturnData(self).grid(row=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could first display the combobox `DataChosenForm(self).grid(row=0, column=0)` without calling the `ReturnData` in the `Application` class.

Then, in the `callback()` method collect the choice `choice = event.widget.get()` and pass it to `ReturnData`. This would mean, however, that the `LabelFrame` is displayed only after a choice is made.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class DataChosenForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        chosen = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="wybór")
        chosen.grid(row=0)
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(chosen)
        self.combo['values'] = ('wizz', 'ryanair', 'lot')
        self.combo.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=80, pady=10)
        self.combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.callback)

    def callback(self, event=None):
        choice = event.widget.get()
        print(choice)
        ReturnData(self, choice).grid(row=1)

class ReturnData(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, choice):
        super().__init__(parent)
        message_box = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="wynik")
        message_box.grid(row=1)
        mb = tk.Label(message_box, text=choice, anchor='nw')
        mb.pack(padx=120, pady=30)

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("program do wyszukiwania cen lotów")
        self.geometry('300x200')
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        DataChosenForm(self).grid(row=0, column=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank for answer but this is not exactly what I looking for. I wanna one frame which is updated when I select option in combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass other class or it's field to `__init__` of the `DataChosenForm`, and to callback function from there, where then you can change class/field directly. Here's what I mean, but I use TreeView:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class ConnectedClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.received = "will be changed"

class TreeViewWrapper(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, master, connected_class, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        parents = []
        for i in range(10):
            parent = self.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i, tags=str(i))
            for i in range(3):
                self.insert(parent, "end", text="Item %s" % i, tags=str(i))
        self.bind("<Control-r>", lambda e: self.pass_to_other(e, connected_class))

    def pass_to_other(self, _, connected_class):
        items = self.selection()
        connected_class.received = items


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.con_class = ConnectedClass()
        self.tree = TreeViewWrapper(self.root,self.con_class)
        self.tree.pack()
        self.root.bind("<Control-p>",lambda e:print(self.con_class.received))
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```